# Component Links not updating with scaled out deployer

Tags: content-delivery, web8, dynamic-linking, cache, web8.5

I have a problem with SDL Web 8 and SDL Web 8.5 whereby Component Links do not update if the target Page is renamed or unpublished. The Links continue to resolve to the old URL - resulting in 404s.

This only occurs when the Deployer is scaled out from the Content Service so we didn't spot this in our development or test environments.

As an aside question: if the Deployer and Content Service are on the same machine, is the Object Cache shared between them - can this be configured?

The only way to fix it is to restart the Content Service which presumably clears the Object Cache.

Support have issued a hotfix for this issue in SDL Web 8 ( CD_8.1.1.3556.) but not yet for SDL Web 8.5

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced the same issue with an SDL Web install as it seems like a key piece of functionality (Component Links) is not working correctly in a fairly common architecture.

So if you have a Web 8 or Web 8.5 install with a deployer on a different server to your Content Service and are using Active MQ to invalidate the cache, when you rename a Page and republish it, do links to that Page update for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now have a hotfix for this in 8.5 as well: CD_8.5.0.3556

You'll need to ask SDL Support for this - while you're at it please ask them for a public hotfix list :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update Rob. The request for a publicly available list of hotfixes is now on the SDL Web Ideas site here: https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/sdl_web_ideas/i/sdl-web-ideas/hotfixes---knowledge-center