# LinkResolving - Can a ComponentLink object be cached 'forever'?

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery

At a customer we have trouble with urls that do not get updated. When a Page is moved up or down in the navigation (Structure Groups), the old URLs are still resolved (which causes 404's).

A custom URL resolver is used and I see that the `ComponentLink` object (`Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Linking`) is cached without any expiration time. That means it will only be created again after the application pool is recycled or website is restarted.

My question: if you cache the `ComponentLink` object, does that result in URLs not being updated when using the `GetLink` method?

**UPDATE**: interesting detail is that after recyclying the IIS App Pool of the application, the links are resolved correctly.

source code:
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

cd_storage_conf.xml:

I couldn't get the XML completely working in this post, so you find it [here](http://pastebin.com/123nAbcz) (Paste Bin). As you can see we publish to file system.

Comment: Can you share some more detail around the exact code you are using, i.e. edit your question and add a source code example of how you use and cache the `ComponentLink` object, together with the configuration of your Deployer and Cache Channel Service?

Comment: I would investigate the cache channel service if you are using it. We have a hotfix for a similar issue on SDL Web 8 - never seen it in 2013 SP1 though. http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16340/component-links-not-updating-with-scaled-out-deployer so it sounds like something not configured correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I will do some more research after my holidays ;)

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett, I updated the post with more info.

Comment: @BartKoopman, I updated the post with more info.

Comment: OK... so it looks like you have your own component link object caching - yes, I would expect that in this case your application never actually gets the link from Tridion CD, and instead will use that. Solution is simple though: add absolute expiration (not sliding) to your cache.Add instruction, maybe with a value of 10 minutes or whatever makes you feel comfortable.

Comment: @NunoLinhares, thanks! So the answer om my question is: NO, don't cache the ComponentLink object (for too long)?

Comment: Yup - that would be the right answer - if you have Tridion cache well configured, there's no real benefit to adding your own on top of it. I would recommend using your own cache layer only for queries, and not standard objects.

Comment: @NunoLinhares, that's useful information, do you mind to add this as a answer? I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't cache these objects indefinitely, as then your web application will not get any updates (unless you restart IIS, as you mention).

So, the best (and fastest) way to achieve this would be to modify your implementation of cache to ensure it uses an "[Absolute Expiration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.absoluteexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx)" model with perhaps a duration of 10 minutes (or whatever makes your editors comfortable).

It is worth stating that with a well configured cache layer (with a working Cache Channel Service) you can rely on Tridion cache to always provide you the latest information available and this removes the need to create your own cache. I would recommend using additional/custom cache for any queries you do on the front-end (keyword queries, schema queries, etc) as these tend to either be invalidated very often (keyword queries will be invalidated every time you publish *any* component) or not be cached at all.